# Reading PDF Files

Tags: android

Is it possible to read a pdf file on Android, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The most you can do is to call another program to open it with something like this (only works if you have Quickoffice installed)

```
    public class OpenPdf extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");

                if (file.exists()) {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } 
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
                            "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't native support PDF. But, you can read your PDF file online by Google Docs Viewer. Here's the code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as native support for PDF of an operating system. It's always additional software!

Answer (score 0):

No. At this time, there is no library that can parse a .pdf byte-by-byte.

Android does have some 3rd party libraries for displaying .pdf's, but Android itself doesn't contain a class/package for doing this either.